# Is it feasible to write a script to automatically update Outlook events from a Excel/CSV file?

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, outlook

I have a challenge that I'm trying to assess the feasibility of and determine the best way to accomplish.

I have 30 contracts that have about 30 events associated with them (that's about 900 total events). These events are all relative to one date on each contract. They need to be imported into an Outlook calendar, and then updated as the single date changes.

The issue is that this date that all the other events revolve around changes frequently, and with it the dates of the other 30 events.

I need a way to update the dates of these events without overwriting any additional information added (i.e. attendees, or meeting details).

Is this possible, and is VBA the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set the AppointmentItem.Start property appropriately.